# Wordpress woocommerce -> in which PHP file <div class="content-area container"> is generated?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce, Which PHP file inside /plugins/woocommerce/ ...... generates the code (?) :

```
<div class="content-area  container">
  <div class="row">
    <main id="main" class="site-main  col-xs-12  col-md-9" role="main">
```

???????????????????

Look at this picture for more details https://i.postimg.cc/bpw42mDf/mega.png

I searched both in:

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php
```

and

```
/wp-content/themes/bolts-pt/page.php
```

...but in neigher can I find this code which I posted above.

I can even erase the whole `page.php` in **bolts-pt theme** and it does not affect the woocommerce product page so that code can't be in `page.php` file in themes/bolts-pt/ folder

Comment: Please find this code in plugins/woocommerce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this path

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/theme-support/class-wc-twenty-nineteen.php

public static function output_content_wrapper() {
    echo '<section id="primary" class="content-area balasaheb">';
    echo '<main id="main" class="site-main">';
}
```

OR Please check hooks

```
woocommerce_before_main_content
```

Comment: Inside /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php there is line add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 ); but I can't find the function woocommerce_output_content_wrapper :)

Comment: Ok I've found function woocommerce_output_content_wrapper inside wc-template-functions.php in which, in turn, there is a reference to global/wrapper-start.php, but in wrapper-start.php althought there are switches like here https://i.postimg.cc/Mw3gqRKp/fdsa.png notice that there is no match like in my OP namely <div class="content-area  container">

Comment: Ok, I've found it, it is inside wp-content/themes/bolts-pt/inc/woocommerce.php -> woocommerce.php from plugin/woocommerce/woocommerse.php file is overriden in the bolts-pt wordpress theme

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is generated from this path:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area"><main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
```

path:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\your-site-name\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\global\wrapper-start.php
```

and closing part of it is:

```
</main></div>
```

that is generated by:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\your-site-name\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\global\wrapper-start.php
```

I am using xampp, that's why the path starts by : `C:\xampp\htdocs\`